# vue i18n unable load translation from locales

Tags: vue.js, internationalization

I'm using vue and add i18n by command

```
vue add i18n
```

After added. i18n unable to load from json files in folder `locales`

Component `HelloI18n.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ t('hello') }}</p>
    <p>{{ t('message') }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

export default ({
  name: 'HelloI18n',
  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n({
      inheritLocale: true,
      useScope: 'local'
    })

    // Something todo ..

    return { t }
  }
})
</script>

<i18n>
{
  "en": {
    "hello": "Hello i18n in SFC!"
  }
}
</i18n>
```

src/locales/en.json

```
{
  "message": "hello i18n !!"
}
```

`<p>{{ t('hello') }}</p>` is worked but `<p>{{ t('message') }}</p>` is not.

Error: `[intlify] Not found 'message' key in 'en' locale messages.`

My repo at: https://github.com/duyetvn/vue-i18n-sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [line](https://github.com/duyetvn/vue-i18n-sample/blob/ab539f6/src/i18n.js#L16) is the problem:

```js
function loadLocaleMessages() {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key) 
    }
  })
  return messages
}
```

`locales(key)` loads the module, but the data is stored in the `default` key within. The fix is to use that key:

```js
messages[locale] = locales(key).default
```

https://github.com/duyetvn/vue-i18n-sample/pull/1